# Recover foundation files in Compass/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, zurb-foundation, compass-sass

I overhauled my CSS and may have removed some of my foundation files.

I get an error whenever I to compile anything with `@import foundation` in it: "File to import not found or unreadable: foundation." However, `require foundation` seems to work and `foundation.css` is served no problem.

Even if I add `require foundation_and_overrides` to `application.scss`, Rails complains about the `@import foundation` at the end of the required file.

Concatenation via `require` alone would be fine if I only wanted to use Foundation's classes/base rules, but I need to use its mixins and variables too, for which I need `@import` to work.

I tried running `compass install foundation` in my assets directory, but even after massaging the files that gives me, I'm left with the same "File to import not found or unreadable: foundation" error (this time in the generated `app.scss`).

**How can I get `@import foundation` to work?**

I'm on Rails 3.2.13.

From my Gemfile:

```
gem 'sass-rails'      # version 3.2.9
gem 'compass'         # version 0.12.2
gem 'zurb-foundation' # version 4.2.1
```

**EDIT**

According to the stack trace, lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:45 is throwing a SyntaxError. That line looks like:

```
paths = @options[:load_paths]
```

which reinforces my suspicion that this is a paths issue, and the sass gem simply can't talk to the foundation gem. I'm not really sure how to investigate further. Help, please and thank you!

Comment: _Seemingly_ related SO questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005361/sass-import-error-in-rails-3-app-file-to-import-not-found-or-unreadable-comp) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630456/sass-import-directive-when-used-in-rails-engine-cant-find-assets-in-plugins) for anyone who's interested. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems I can get what I want by using the "watch" method. For that to work, I had to create `config/compass.rb`. Here's what I put in it:

```
require 'zurb-foundation'

http_path = "/"
sass_dir = 'app/assets/stylesheets'
css_dir = 'app/assets/stylesheets'
images_dir = 'app/assets/images'
javascript_dir = 'app/assets/javascripts'
```

Then, from my application root, I ran `compass watch`.

Answer (score 0):

For getting back the foundation files, trying

```
rails g foundation:install
```

should add foundation_and_overrides.scss back to your asset pipeline

or if you don't want to use the generator

```
/*= require foundation */
```

in app/assets/stylesheet/application.css

and

```
@import "foundation_and_overrides";
```

to app/assets/stylesheets/amn.scss

For the second part of your question, correct me if I'm wrong but I believe the scss files are being loaded from the foundation gem

Comment: Thanks for clarifying about the foundation gem. My main problem remains, I've edited to clarify.

Comment: Have you tried adding 'gem install compass-rails' to your Gemfile, looking at the Foundation documentation (http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/rails.html) and it has a comment next to compass-rails "# you need this or you get an err"